# ROS2 and TypeError when publishing custom message to Topic

Tags: python, ros2

I have defined a custom message: `uint8[] data`

The custom message is imported in my Node class with no problems:

```
from my_shared.msg import MyMessage
```

In the same Node, I create the publisher with:

`self.my_publisher = self.create_publisher(MyMessage, 'topic_in', 200)`

and I publish the message with:

```
self.my_publisher.publish(my_msg)
```

my_msg is built in the following way:

```
payload_bitstream = np.fromstring(my_data, np.uint8) my_msg = payload_bitstream.tolist()
```

Sadly, I get a TypeError:

`File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rclpy/publisher.py", line 68, in publish raise TypeError() TypeError`

Could you help out with this if you know what I am doing wrong pls?

Thanks in advance, G.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by how I was creating and assigning value to the message.

The right way in ROS2 is:

```
my_msg = MyMessage()

...

my_msg.data = my_value
```

that did the trick and solved my problem

Comment: Then please accept your own answer, so your original question does not appear under the unanswered questions. Thanks